# Keep statistic about sorting algorithms

Tags: c#, sorting, oop

I have a homework about object oriented programming in c#. a part of my homework, I need to make 2 different sorting algorithms and putting the random numbers into them and observing statistic about 2 different algorithms. 
about that my teaches said me in e-mail "*Non static sorting class can keep statistic about sorting how many numbers, how fast, min, max, average..*"

So there are my sorting algorithms which Insertion and Count Sortings. Please tell me how can i keep statistic about sorting.

Don't forget main subject of my homework is OOP.

```
class InsertionSorting : Sort    
{
    public override List<int> Sorting(List<int> SortList)
    {

        for ( int i=0; i<SortList.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j= i+1; j>0; j--)
            {
                if (SortList[j-1] > SortList [j])
                {
                    int temp = SortList[j - 1];
                    SortList[j - 1] = SortList[j];
                    SortList[j] = temp;
                }
            }                                
        }
        return SortList;
    }
}



class CountSorting : Sort
{
    public override List<int> Sorting(List<int> SortList)
    {
        int n = SortList.Count;
        List<int> output = new List<int>();
        List<int> count = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            count.Add(0);
            output.Add(0);                
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            ++count[SortList[i]];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 999; ++i)
            count[i] += count[i - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            output[count[SortList[i]] - 1] = SortList[i];
            --count[SortList[i]];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SortList.Count; i++)
            SortList[i] = output[i];

        return SortList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting is being done in two classes - InsertionSorting & CountSorting.

If you want keep track of the statistics declare a variable in the class and increment it every iteration etc etc. Then you can see which one is more effective.

E.g

```
class InsertionSorting : Sort    
{
    private int iterations = 0
    ...
        for (int j= i+1; j>0; j--)
        {
            if (SortList[j-1] > SortList [j])
            {
                iterations++
                ...
```

You could also declare a startTime and endTime allowing to you determine the time the sort took. At the start of "Sorting" record the start time and just before you return record the end time. Write a method to report the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your prof has told you how when they said "...statistics about sorting how many numbers, how fast, min, max, average.." Your best bet here is to create a class such as "Statistics" which contains a method that allows user input, either through args or direct user prompt. The variables should be as easy as "count of numbers to sort" "lower bounds of number range", "upper bound of number range", and, if automating the testing process, "number of times to iterate".

Given answers to these questions, you should run the two sorting algos with them (eg use a random number generator, and max and min to generate a list.) Your sorting algos need an addition to "log" these statistics. Most likely a variable that tracks the number of position swaps that occurred in the array.

I'm not about to write out your homework for you (that's your job, and you should get good at it.) But if you have any more questions to this, I may be able to steer you in the right direction if this is too vague and you are still struggling.